# Error: write after end - node post request (module) pipe post request in get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a REST API server which is running on one VM1. On other VM2 machine I have built a node js server which is running as proxy. On the same VM2 machine I have application (hosted with apache which serves only html, js and css files). My node js server only resends the api calls back to the API server. This is working fine, until new requirement arrive - to add a new API endpoint (on the node js server) to download files (csv). In order to make download happen, I need to use GET method. The thing is that the required data is available only on POST endpoint from the main API server, and I am calling the API endpoint to get the data and send it back. This is the code I am trying to work it out:

```
var express = require('express');  
var cors = require('cors');
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var csv = require("fast-csv");

var config = require("./config.js");

var corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    var originIsWhitelisted = config.whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
  }
};

var handler = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
};

var app = express();  

// Enable CORS for all requests
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions)); // specially for pre-flight requests

app.get('/download', function(req, res){
    var limit = req.query.limit;
    var offset = req.query.offset;

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: config.apiServerHost + '/search',
        useQuerystring: true,
        qs: {'limit': limit, 'offset': offset},
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        body: 'from=date&to=date'
    };

    var filename = 'data.csv';
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=\"data.csv\"');
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/csv');

    var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({
      headers: true,
      objectMode: true,
      transform: function (row) {
        return row;
      }
    });
    console.log(options);

    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
           csvStream.write({
             "col1": "value1-"+data[0][i],
             "col2": "value2-"+data[1][i],
             "col3": "value3-"+data[2][i],
             "col4": "value4-"+data[3][i]
           });
         }
         csvStream.end();
      }
      else {
        console.log("Error:", error, body);
      }

    }

    req.pipe(request(options, callback));//.pipe(res)
    csvStream.pipe(res);
});

app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
    var url = config.apiServerHost + req.url;
    console.log(url);

    req.pipe(request({
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        "url": url
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleString(), error);
        }
    })).pipe(res);
});
```

This all code works fine when request method is POST (the same as main API server). However I receive **"[Error: write after end]"** when I add the body in `options` object. Can someone help me figure out what is happening and how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `[Error: write after end]` show pip data after `.end()`, for your codes

> ```
> req.pipe(request(options, callback));//.pipe(res)
> csvStream.pipe(res);
> ```

In the `callback` function, the `csvStream.end();` is called, then invoke `csvStream.pipe` could cause this error.